# Как сделать цвет одинаковых дивов разными для гостя и юзера?

Tags: php, css, laravel, sass

Как сделать цвета для зарегестрированного пользователя например черным, а для гостя зеленым в одном диве на php laravel?

Answer (score 1):

```
<div @if(Auth::check()) class="black" @elseif class="green" @endif >
```